# Instantiate a COM Object in c#

Tags: c#, com, reference, instantiation

The more reading I do on this, the more confused I get.

We have a large solution developed in c#, and it has a project that is set up as a COM object. The project I am working on is in another solution, but I need to load that COM object. I've tried using TlbImp to create a map so I can do early loading of the object, but I get an error T10000: The input file ... is not a valid type library. I've loaded this as a COM object in VFP, so I know it is a COM object (which may be different from what this message is telling me).

I've looked into adding a reference to it in VS, but I am told "the activex type library was exported from a .net assembly and cannot be added as a reference". A search on this brought up a suggestion of adding a reference using the Browse tab, but this would create a link that would need to be changed on each developer's system depending on their directory structure. I would also rather not include a copy of the dll; this is a COM object, so including the dll seems to defeat the purpose.

I've also looked into late binding, but I don't like the speed hit that I would have to take. This can't be as difficult as it seems to be; I am sure I am missing some very simple thing. If anyone can provide insight into my situation, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I *suspect* that Microsoft's implementation of COM interop did not anticipate that someone would want to link CCWs and RCWs together like that. Would it not be simpler to just reference your .NET assembly directly and ignore COM interop entirely?

Comment: I think it would, but I am working from a different department, so technically am not supposed to have access to the code. Since other people may need to work on my project, creating a hard-coded link to a solution that not everyone has would make things too difficult for others, which is why I am trying to handle this in COM. My team works on the older version, which was build using VFP, and is stored in a completely different source control.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "difficult". Adding a COM reference is creating a hard-coded link to another solution as well, but with more baggage (and some DLL Hell layered on top). Maybe you could ask the other team to add the compiled DLL into source control, or create an installer that puts it in the GAC, then you can treat it like a 3rd party component.

Comment: Could you not just contact the "keeper of the keys" to the other project and ask for the latest, greatest, formal controlled release of the relevant assembly with the exposed COM object(s) you need, and add that as your reference? Perhaps I'm oversimplifying things..but it seems you're making a hard link no matter what.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is very unclear.  It isn't like it is not impossible to fool the IDE to get a C# program to load the [ComVisible] component anyway, using late-binding with the *dynamic* keyword is a simple way.  It is that it is just utterly pointless to actually do this.  You won't actually test the component the way it is going to be used by the client code, the CLR short-circuits the COM interface anyway.  So just test it by adding the assembly reference directly.  If you don't know how to use FoxPro then there's an RTFM for that.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I think I will take this information, and try to persuade my supervisor.